# Creating a textarea with Strong, Italic, underline buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

probably some of you had follow my previous questions, I'm developing a simple guestbook in order to learn php. Yesterday I've implemented the function to delete messages from the guestbook.
Today I want to allow users to format their message with like every form (also here on stackoverflow)
I want to add some buttons [B] [I] [U] which will format their messages on the guestbook (only their messages) with bold, italic and underline (in future I think I'll allow to choose colors of the message).

How can I do this? Which language I have to use? (By now I'm using php,html and css but I know something about javascript, ajax, jquery)

Some details:

```
<div id="functions">
    <form method=post id="addForm" name="addForm" action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>>
        <span class="label" style="text-align: center"> Comment </span> <textarea class="text" type=text cols=55 rows="7" name="comment"></textarea><br>
        <br><input class="submit" type=submit name=submit value="Submit">
    </form>
    <a href=viewGuest.php>View Guestbook!</a>

</div>
```

All comments are stored in a mysql database but I don't think this is relevant.

Comment: Once formatting do you need to save the format or just for visualization??

Comment: I will save it in the database in order to show it all times he will look at the guestbook

Comment: There are tons of free editors around, using javascript and/or jQuery. Just Google for something like `free text rich editor javascript jquery` and it gives you at least ten sites with overviews of WYSIWYG editors. Some simple, some more complex. I'm sure there is one that fullfills your needs.

Comment: You can use TinyMCE http://www.tinymce.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You coud make use of a javascript component, like CKeditor (http://ckeditor.com/). It will allow you add HTML content for your guestbook, and therefore, you could make use of HTML tags for bolds, italics,...

Comment: I downloaded the zip, now how can I add it to my form?

Comment: I recommend that you take a look at some samples, like [this](http://nightly.ckeditor.com/15-06-10-06-09/standard/samples/replacebycode.html). But the basic idea is that you create a TextaArea with the content and call **CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );**, and the editor should appear

Comment: If you just want a simple rich text editor, don't use CKeditor. It is good, but pretty complex and has tons of features you'll probably never use, when I read your question. Go for a more simple one.

Comment: I'll check your answer as "solved the problem" because you set me on the right way. I didn't choose ckeditor  because it was too much complex, I needed something very simple, only three buttons, so I choose this one [link](http://coursesweb.net/javascript/texarea-buttons-format-text-colors-smiles_s2) Thanks you!

Comment: You could also try [downloading](http://ckeditor.com/download) the basic package, which just includes the basic features or even customize your own package. Anyway, if your option fits your needs, go for it :-)